# Duplicates of Document ID Generator in Document Library after adding Content Type

Tags: document-library, content-type, event-receivers, document-id

On a Sharepoint 2010 server with the Document ID service activated I have a document library with content type management enabled. After adding a content type that I've created in Sharepoint Designer there are duplicates of the Document ID Generators as shown in the screenshot. I've also tried adding built-in content types such as video, or audio and I get the same behaviour.

[image: Displaying event receivers of a document library]

My understanding was that aside from any custom event receivers there should only be four there. The four being ItemAdded, ItemUpdated, ItemCheckedIn, and ItemUncheckedOut. Is my understanding flawed?

Also, it doesn't appear to be a one-to-one correlation between number of content types and number of these receivers. On a different server there are document libraries with 50+ content types and 100+ event receivers.
Checked on a fresh SharePoint 2013 server and the same issue is happening.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar scenario. In our productive system we have 14 content types and 112 "Document ID Generator" Event Receivers.
So for each content type 8 Event Receivers.

But we create subsites from a site template. The site template has only 56 Event Receivers, so 4 per content type.

My guess is that when creating a new site from a template it gets doubled, just don't know if it is ok?

Maybe a site template is not allowed to have document ID feature activated?

Edit: I at least found that 4 event receivers per content type is usual:
[Look Here](http://www.reality-tech.com/sharepoint-document-ids/)

There it is written:

> When the Document ID Service is enabled for a Site Collection, Event Receivers are automatically installed in each Document Library.  Actually there is a set of Event Receivers installed for each and every Content Type configured within that document library.  The Event Receiver is called “Document ID Generator” and is configured to by fired synchronously.  There is a separate Event Receiver for the following events:
>
> ItemAdded ItemUpdated ItemCheckedIn ItemUncheckedOut